# Do I need to protect Laravel ::post routes from any kind of post besides my own form

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.7

If I have two routes:

```
Route::get('/setup', 'SetupController@index')
Route::post('/setup' 'SetupController@store')
```

In the `SetupController@index` I do some checks, for example I check if the user is authentificated. But there are some more rules there that I check.

Should I perform the same checks on the `post` route too?

Is there any way someone could hit that post route without hitting the `get` route first? (for example posting in url `http://domain/setup?password=1234`)

So I guess what I am asking is :

**Do I need to wrap the two routes in a middleware and do checks on each of them or is enough to check on the `get` route?**

Comment: Your POST routes are *protected* by https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf. Also yea if you have some kind of role/permissions set up you need to check that for both types.

Comment: Yes, you could wrap in middleware and make check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you need to wrap both routes in the middleware.

someone can open anypage (login for example) and edit the html to make a form that point to `/setup` and put whatever he wants in it.

sure, that someone need to know the architecture of the form to do this, but it's a risk nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you need to add corresponding middlewares for different urls, for the get route, you can use ReplayAttackMiddleware for unnecessary attacks; and for the post route, I think you need to add different roles for different users, and JWT is a really good tool for authentication.